# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Tags: javascript

I filter my object but get the error

> Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Here is my code:

```
// tex is from <TextInput />
const inputName = tex.toString().trim().toLowerCase();

let filterData = [];

console.log('searchMovie =>', searchMovie);

searchMovie.filter(item => { 
  if (item.enName !== null || item.cnName !== null) {
    console.log('item.enName =>', item.enName);
    console.log('item.cnName =>', item.cnName);
    filterData = searchMovie.filter(({ enName, cnName }) => 
      enName.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputName) >= 0 || 
      cnName.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputName) >= 0 
    );
  } 
});
```

Here is debug view
[image]

I found the problem comes from `enName`, because when I change the code like

```
enName.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputName) >= 0
```

The error will become as below:

> Cannot read property 'toString' of null

Why my enName's value `Three Husbands` cause the error ?

Is any way to avoid it ?

Comment: `Why my enName's value Three Husbands cause the error ?` - that wouldn't be the problem, but having `searchMovie.filter` inside `searchMovie.filter` looks completely odd

Comment: If I had to guess, at least one of your `searchMovie` items does **not** contain an `enName` property (or it does and is `null`). A simple `console.log` within the inner `filter` would tell you exactly what the data looks like

Comment: @JaromandaX Because my data cnName or enName possibly is null, so I have to check it by if-else

Comment: What is it you're trying to do here? The nested `filter` doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Morton - that makes zero sense

Comment: Yes you right, because when I console.log('enName', enName), I found the null value, it looks like I set the nested filter doesn't make any sense. I know how to fix it now.

Comment: I think what you want is `return (item.enName !== null && item.enName.toLowerCase().includes(inputName)) || (item.cnName !== null && item.cnName.toLowerCase().includes(inputName))`. No nested `filter` required

Comment: Yes, Phil your suggestion is correct. Would you post an answer ? I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the first time when the component is rendered, the inputName is null and when you are trying to filter, the method is called at the first time and it is receiving null.

inputName = null

You also need to check inputName !== null